# ssh backspace deletes one character instead of two (utf-8 symbols)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, encoding, utf-8, ssh

Im accessing a remote computer using ssh and running a bash command to input symbols using standard input stream:

> read test;echo $test

It's ok to input english letters and use backspace to delete them, then input other characters and iterate this steps any amount of times.
But it becomes a disaster when I use other utf-8 symbols, like russian ones, which require 2 bytes instead of 1, as english ones do.
E.g., I input:

> абвгдежз

After that, I use backspace for 8 times, and input other symbols:

> привет

And press Enter key. But instead of the result which would equal my last input, I get the following:

> абвгпривет

Which means that 8 backspace deleted only 4 symbols.

I do use linux ubuntu 12.04. Tried different consoles: standard one, terminator; different types of backspace options (as ASCII-del or Ctrl+H); setting $LC_TYPE to ru_RU.UTF-8, but nothing works. 
There is no such a problem using local console.
Thank you in advance.

update: I've also got a video of this issue, please [watch it at youtube](http://youtu.be/Erbmnq1z1tY)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around this by running

`stty iutf8`

on the server each time you ssh there.
Unfortunately this bug exists since 2005 year, watch though [the debian forums](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=337041) for details.
You may also want to add this line at the end of your .bashrc file.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `LC_CTYPE` to a UTF-8 locale, e.g. `ru_RU.UTF-8` or `en_US.UTF-8`. You can list available locales using `locale -a`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've already got $LC_TYPE set up as ru_RU.UTF-8 both on client and server side. Sadly, that does not resolve an issue.

Comment: @VsevolodAvramov Did you try to `export` that variable? And: When did you set it? If you set it in the shell, it might be too late...

Comment: @glglgl, I've got the following configuaration:
1) First lines of ~/.ssh/config are:
Host *
SendEnv LC_*
2) AcceptEnv directive is present in the server configuration at /etc/ssh/sshd_config
3) First lines of ~/.bashrc both on client- and serverside are export LC_CTYPE=ru_RU.utf8
4) locale -a shows ru_RU.utf8 in the list of available options for locale.
Any more ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @glglgl I've also recorded a video which proves that variable LC_ENV is set up properly. Please [watch it at youtube](http://youtu.be/Erbmnq1z1tY)